# Multiple solutions of coupled system of equations

Tags: equation-solving

I want to plot this equation:

```
 y=x-I*rho12
```

where rho12 can be obtained by solving coupled system of equations with multiple solutions. How can I hold on all these possible solutions such that for each value of x we found multiple values of y?

I tried

```
y=x-I*rho12/.%
```

but I got this error.. is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, 
and so cannot be used for replacing

This is my code with my attempt to solve the equations but I got errors about working precision:

```
e = 1.6*10^-19;\[HBar] = 6.626*10^-34/(2*Pi);\[Gamma]m = 1*10^14;\[Epsilon]0 = 8.85*10^-12;kb = 1.381*10^-23;ef = 1.36*1.602*10^-19;c = 3*10^8;tem = 300;\[Lambda] = 570*10^-9;\[Omega] = 2*Pi*c/\[Lambda];\[Omega]p = 1.36*10^16;(*For the dimensions in the system;*)lx = 0.5*10^-9;d = lx;lz = 7*10^-9;ly = Liz;R = 15*10^-9;vg = lx*ly*lz;vm = (4/3)*Pi*R^3;(* For the angles in the system:% Note that theta_M& theta_G are \variables*)\[Phi]1 = Pi - 0.5*Pi - \[Theta]g;\[Phi]2 = Pi - 0.5*Pi - \[Theta]m;\[Theta]q = \[Phi]1 + \[Phi]2;\[Theta]g = 1;\[Theta]m = 0.4;(* For the QD to be used in the system:mu_12=1e-29;mu_13=mu_12*)\\[Mu]12 = \[Mu]13 = 10^-29;\[Gamma]12 = 2*10^9;\[Gamma]13 = \[Gamma]12;\[Gamma]32 = 0.35*\[Gamma]12;\[Gamma]q = 0.5*(\[Gamma]12 + \[Gamma]13 + \[Gamma]32);(*For the dielectric functions in the system:*)\[Epsilon]b = 12.9;\[Epsilon]q = 6.5;\[Epsilon]\[Infinity] = 5.7;\[Epsilon] = (2*\[Epsilon]b + \[Epsilon]q)/(3*\[Epsilon]b);\[Gamma]g = 7.34*10^11;\[Sigma] = ((e^2*2*
    Pi)/(8*\[HBar])*(Tanh[(\[HBar]*\[Omega] + 2 ef)/(4*kb*tem)] + 
   Tanh[(\[HBar]*\[Omega] - 2 ef)/(4*kb*tem)]) + (-I*e^2*2*
   Pi/(8*Pi*\[HBar]))*(Log[(\[HBar]*\[Omega] + 
       2 ef)^2/((\[HBar]*\[Omega] - 2 ef)^2 + (2 kb*
         tem)^2)]) + (I*e^2*2*
   Pi/(\[HBar]*Pi))*(ef/(\[HBar]*\[Omega] + I*\[HBar]*\[Gamma]g)));\[Epsilon]g = 1 + I*\[Sigma]*(1/(\[Omega]*lx*\[Epsilon]0));\[Epsilon]m = \[Epsilon]\[Infinity] - \[Omega]p^2/(\[Omega]^2 + 
I*\[Omega]*\[Gamma]m);(*For the system polarizability*)\[Zeta]x = 1 - Pi*lx/(2*lz);\[Zeta]z = Pi*lx/(4*lz);\[Alpha]gx = 4*Pi*vg*(\[Epsilon]g - \[Epsilon]b)/(3*\[Epsilon]b + 
  3*\[Zeta]x*(\[Epsilon]g - \[Epsilon]b));\[Alpha]gz = 4*Pi*vg*(\[Epsilon]g - \[Epsilon]b)/(3*\[Epsilon]b + 
  3*\[Zeta]z*(\[Epsilon]g - \[Epsilon]b));\[Alpha]m = vm*((\[Epsilon]m - \[Epsilon]b)/(\[Epsilon]m + 2*\[Epsilon]b));(* For the distances in the system:% Note that R_GM is a variable;*)Rqg = (Sin[\[Theta]m]/Sin[\[Theta]q]*Rgm);Rqm = (Sin[\[Theta]g]/Sin[\[Theta]q]*Rgm);Rgm = 23*10^-9;\[CapitalPi]x = (1/(4*
   Pi*\[Epsilon]))*(\[Alpha]gx*(3*Cos[\[Phi]1] - 1)/
   Rqg^3 + \[Alpha]m*(3*Cos[\[Phi]2] - 1)/Rqm^3);\[CapitalPi]z = (1/(4*
   Pi*\[Epsilon]))*(\[Alpha]gz*(3*Cos[\[Theta]g] - 1)/
   Rqg^3 + \[Alpha]m*(3*Cos[\[Theta]m] - 1)/Rqm^3);\[CapitalPhi]x = (-1*\[Alpha]gx*\[Alpha]m/((Rgm^3)*(4*
       Pi*\[Epsilon])^2))*((3*Cos[\[Phi]1] - 1)/
  Rqg^3 + (3*Cos[\[Phi]2] - 1)/Rqm^3);\[CapitalPhi]z = (2*\[Alpha]gz*\[Alpha]m/((Rgm^3)*(4*
       Pi*\[Epsilon])^2))*((3*Cos[\[Theta]g] - 1)/Rqg^3 + 
 3*Cos[\[Theta]m] - 1/Rqm^3);\[CapitalLambda]x = (\[Mu]12^2/(2*
   Pi*(4*Pi*\[Epsilon])^2*(\[HBar]*\[Epsilon]0*\[Epsilon]b)))*(\\[Alpha]gx*(3*Cos[\[Phi]1] - 1)^2/
   Rqg^6 + \[Alpha]m*(3*Cos[\[Phi]2] - 1)^2/Rqm^6);\[CapitalLambda]z = (\[Mu]13^2/(2*
   Pi*(4*Pi*\[Epsilon])^2*(\[HBar]*\[Epsilon]0*\[Epsilon]b)))*(\\[Alpha]gz*(3*Cos[\[Theta]g] - 1)^2/
   Rqg^6 + \[Alpha]m*(3*Cos[\[Theta]m] - 1)^2/Rqm^6);a1 = 2;(*\[Gamma]13/\[Gamma]12*)a2 = 0;(*\[CapitalDelta]p/\[Gamma]12*)\a3 = 3;(*\[CapitalOmega]c/\[Gamma]12*)a4 = 0;(*\[CapitalDelta]c/\\[Gamma]12*)a5 = 2;(*\[Gamma]32/\[Gamma]12*)a6 = 0;(*\[Gamma]32/\\[Gamma]12*)eqs = {-(a1/2 + 1/2)*\[Rho]12 - I*a2*\[Rho]12 + 
 I*\[CapitalLambda]x/\[Gamma]12*(\[Rho]22 - \[Rho]11)*\[Rho]12 + 
 I*x*(\[CapitalPi]x + \[CapitalPhi]x)*(\[Rho]22 - \[Rho]11) + 
 I*a3*(\[CapitalPi]z + \[CapitalPhi]z)*\[Rho]32 + 
 I*\[CapitalLambda]z/\[Gamma]12*\[Rho]13*\[Rho]32 == 
0 && -(1/2 + a1/2)*\[Rho]21 + I*\[Rho]21 - 
 I*Conjugate[\[CapitalLambda]x]/\[Gamma]12*(\[Rho]22 - \[Rho]11)*\\[Rho]21 - 
 I*x*Conjugate[(\[CapitalPi]x + \[CapitalPhi]x)]*(\[Rho]22 - \\[Rho]11) - 
 I*a3*Conjugate[(\[CapitalPi]z + \[CapitalPhi]z)]*\[Rho]23 - 
 I*Conjugate[\[CapitalLambda]z]/\[Gamma]12*\[Rho]31*\[Rho]23 == 
0 && -(1/2 + a1/2)*\[Rho]13 - I*a4*\[Rho]13 + 
 I*\[CapitalLambda]z/\[Gamma]12*(\[Rho]33 - \[Rho]11)*\[Rho]13 + 
 I*a3*(\[CapitalPi]z + \[CapitalPhi]z)*(\[Rho]33 - \[Rho]11) + 
 I*x*(\[CapitalPi]x + \[CapitalPhi]x)*\[Rho]23 + 
 I*\[CapitalLambda]x/\[Gamma]12*\[Rho]12*\[Rho]23 == 
0 && -(1/2 + a1/2)*\[Rho]31 + I*a4*\[Rho]31 - 
 I*Conjugate[\[CapitalLambda]z]/\[Gamma]12*(\[Rho]33 - \[Rho]11)*\\[Rho]31 - 
 I*a3*Conjugate[(\[CapitalPi]z + \[CapitalPhi]z)]*(\[Rho]33 - \\[Rho]11) - 
 I*x*Conjugate[(\[CapitalPi]x1 + \[CapitalPhi]x1)]*\[Rho]32 - 
 I*Conjugate[\[CapitalLambda]x1]/\[Gamma]12*\[Rho]21*\[Rho]32 == 
0 && -(a5/2)*\[Rho]32 - I*a6*\[Rho]32 + I*a4*\[Rho]32 + 
 I*a3*Conjugate[\[CapitalPi]z + \[CapitalPhi]z]*\[Rho]12 + 
 I*Conjugate[\[CapitalLambda]z]/\[Gamma]12*\[Rho]13*\[Rho]12 - 
 I*x*(\[CapitalPi]x + \[CapitalPhi]x)*\[Rho]31 - 
 I*\[CapitalLambda]x/\[Gamma]12*\[Rho]12*\[Rho]31 == 
0 && -(a5/2)*\[Rho]23 + I*a6*\[Rho]23 - I*a4*\[Rho]23 - 
 I*a3*\[Rho]21*(\[CapitalPi]z + \[CapitalPhi]z) - 
 I*\[CapitalLambda]z/\[Gamma]12*\[Rho]31*\[Rho]21 + 
 I*x*Conjugate[(\[CapitalPi]x + \[CapitalPhi]x)]*\[Rho]13 + 
 I*Conjugate[\[CapitalLambda]x]/\[Gamma]12*\[Rho]21*\[Rho]13 == 
0 && -(1 + a1)*\[Rho]11 + 
 I*x*(\[CapitalPi]x + \[CapitalPhi]x)*\[Rho]21 + 
 I*\[CapitalLambda]x/\[Gamma]12*\[Rho]12*\[Rho]21 + 
 I*a3*(\[CapitalPi]z + \[CapitalPhi]z)*\[Rho]31 + 
 I*\[CapitalLambda]z/\[Gamma]12*\[Rho]13*\[Rho]31 + 
 Conjugate[I*x*(\[CapitalPi]x + \[CapitalPhi]x)]*\[Rho]12 + 
 Conjugate[I*\[CapitalLambda]x]/\[Gamma]12*\[Rho]21*\[Rho]12 + 
 Conjugate[I*a3*(\[CapitalPi]z + \[CapitalPhi]z)]*\[Rho]13 + 
 Conjugate[I*\[CapitalLambda]z]/\[Gamma]12*\[Rho]31*\[Rho]13 == 
0 && \[Rho]11 + a5*\[Rho]33 - 
 I*\[CapitalOmega]p*(\[CapitalPi]x1 + \[CapitalPhi]x1)*\[Rho]21 - 
 I*\[CapitalLambda]x/\[Gamma]12*\[Rho]12*\[Rho]21 + 
 Conjugate[-I*x*(\[CapitalPi]x + \[CapitalPhi]x)]*\[Rho]12 + 
 Conjugate[-I*\[CapitalLambda]x1]/\[Gamma]12*\[Rho]21*\[Rho]12 == 
0 && (-a5*\[Rho]33 + a1*\[Rho]11) - 
 I*a3*(\[CapitalPi]z + \[CapitalPhi]z)*\[Rho]31 - 
 I*\[CapitalLambda]z/\[Gamma]12*\[Rho]13*\[Rho]31 + 
 I*Conjugate[a3*(\[CapitalPi]z + \[CapitalPhi]z)]*\[Rho]13 + 
 I*Conjugate[\[CapitalLambda]z]/\[Gamma]12*\[Rho]31*\[Rho]13 == 0};rat[x_] = Rationalize[eqs, 0];nsol[x_] := NSolve[rat[x], {\[Rho]12, \[Rho]13, \[Rho]31, \[Rho]21, \[Rho]11, \[Rho]22, \\[Rho]33, \[Rho]23, \[Rho]32}, WorkingPrecision -> 1000]tab1 = Table[{x -> Input, nsol[Input]}, {Input, 0, 50, 5}];mb = -I*150*\[Rho]21;y = Abs[x - mb]; ListLinePlot[Table[{x /. tab1[[i, 1]], y /. tab1[[i, 2, 5]]}, {i, 1, 20}], Frame -> True, BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 19},FrameLabel -> {"Input field", "Output field"}, InterpolationOrder -> 3, PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {0, 30}}]
```

Comment: In general, it is better to give here the code for your equations and their solutions. In this case we can help you precisely. However, let `sol=Solve[equations, variables]` where `equations` is your list of equations and `variables`- list of variables. Then `Length[sol]` returns the number of solutions. `rho12/.sol[[n]]` where `n=1, 2,...,Length[sol]` substitutes the solution number `n` into `rho12`. I would like to attract your attention that Mma does not plot functions with complex values. For this reason, you only obtain some plot, if `rho12/.sol[[n]]` will be purely imaginary.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind kelp. I hope to provide my code but I could not insert it within comment. In fact, rho12 takes complex values. Is there any way to insert my code here to be able to clarify the problem.

Comment: You should insert your code into the question itself, rather than into comment. Find "edit" link below your question. By clicking this link you will reopen your question for editing. This link is always available for you to modify your question. Further, if your solution is complex, think about plotting its real and imaginary parts separately.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have updated my question providing the code after I had  understood what I exactly want . Just I need your help to fix the obtained errors errors.